# Use Default logon ID in Sharpoint 2013 task list

Tags: 2013, list

I have a list that I am using for data entry by multiple users.  Each user signs into Sharepoint user their own unique network ID.  I would like that ID to default in the "Created By", or any column, without the user manually entering it.  I cannot use Designer on my system.

Comment: The AD Accountname of the user who created an item will be displayed in the Created By column. Created By is a system field you have no control over.